# Zoom Video SDK not working on WebView IOS

Tags: expo, zoom-sdk

I integrated a video streaming feature on an existing web app and this webapp is actually used on the Mobile(expo) side which it is integrated as a web view now on IOS the video stream feature is not working and keeps getting an error

```
TypeError: navigator.mediaDevices is not an Object. (evaluating '"getDisplayMedia"in navigator.mediaDevices')
```

so the issue is that i think this is a webview issue and not mine but is there anything i can do to fix this on my end on the web app end im using vue js and laravel as an api

Answer (score 0):

Zoom Developer Advocate here.

The Zoom Video SDK does support iOS WebViews, here is the [documentation](https://developers.zoom.us/blog/video-sdk-ios-webview/).

However, from the `getDisplayMedia` error, it seems like you are attempting to initiate a screenshare from the iOS WebView.

Currently iOS Safari/WebKit/WebView [does not support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_mediadevices_getdisplaymedia) the [`getDisplayMedia` browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia).